# Add items price together in a listview android

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, addition

I have a listview containing items name and price i made my code so when i click on one item it displays its price in a small dialog box at the bottom of the screen but now when i click another item i want to add that item's price to the first one and so on..

Here is my code for now:

```
 @Override
        public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) // inflating the layout and initializing widgets
        {

            View rowView = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listcontent, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.textName = rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                viewHolder.textData = rowView.findViewById(R.id.details);
                viewHolder.textImage = rowView.findViewById(R.id.price);
                viewHolder.producticon = rowView.findViewById(R.id.producticon);
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            // here setting up names and images
            viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).getProname() + "");
            viewHolder.textData.setText(parkingList.get(position).getData());
           viewHolder.textImage.setText(parkingList.get(position).getImage());
            Picasso.with(context).load(parkingList.get(position).getProducticon()).into(viewHolder.producticon);


            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                    //What happens when you click on a place!
//                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoggedIn.this,MapsActivity.class);
//                    startActivity(intent);
                    final int count = 0;

                    LayoutInflater inflater2 = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    final Dialog mBottomSheetDialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.MaterialDialogSheet);
                    View content =  inflater2.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, null);
                    mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(content);
                    TextView textView = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.mebuyss);
                    final TextView itemcount = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.itemcount);
                    Button plus = (Button) content.findViewById(R.id.plus);
                    Button minus = (Button) content.findViewById(R.id.minus);
                    Button finish = (Button) content.findViewById(R.id.finishgettingitem);
                    textView.setText(parkingList.get(position).getProname());
                    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                           counter = counter + 1;
                           itemcount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                        }
                    });
                    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            counter --;
                            if(counter<0){
                                counter=0;
                            }
                            itemcount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                        }
                    });
                    final Dialog mBottomSheetDialog2 = new Dialog(context, R.style.MaterialDialogSheet);
                    final View content2 =  inflater2.inflate(R.layout.smalldialog, null);
                    final TextView total = (TextView) content2.findViewById(R.id.totalpriceofsmalldialog);
                    total.setText(null);
                    finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String get = itemcount.getText().toString();
                            Float last = Float.parseFloat(get) * Float.parseFloat(parkingList.get(position).getImage());
                            mBottomSheetDialog.dismiss();


                            mBottomSheetDialog2.setContentView(content2);
                            mBottomSheetDialog2.setCancelable(false);
                            mBottomSheetDialog2.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            mBottomSheetDialog2.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

                            total.setText(String.valueOf(last));
                            mBottomSheetDialog2.show();
                            mBottomSheetDialog2.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
                            mBottomSheetDialog2.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
                            doneonce = true;
                        }
                    });
//                    if (doneonce = true){
//                        Float priceofitem = parseFloat(parkingList.get(position).getImage());
//                        Float currentprice = parseFloat(total.getText().toString());
//                        Float finalfloat = priceofitem * currentprice;
//                        total.setText(String.valueOf(finalfloat));
//
//                    }
                    mBottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
                    if (!mBottomSheetDialog.isShowing()){
                        counter = 1;
                    }
//

                    mBottomSheetDialog.show();






                }
            });



            return rowView;
        }
```

I tried using boolean but it didn't go as well as i expected.
I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Is all of your code (the `getView()` method) within your ArrayAdapter class? If so, move you listener register out into your Activity, and then the listener needs only pull the required value from the selected item and append it to a property of your Activity class, and then raise the view to show the running total.